# Prometheus idelta function does show result as expected

Tags: prometheus

I have a metric which is "order_created", it is a counter. I want to show number of orders created per minute.

I tried "idelta", but seems that the result is not as expected. Did I misunderstand the meaning of "idelta"? Which function should I use?

Any advice is appreciated.

Here's my testing result:
When I use `order_created` to retrieve data, you can see that it growed from 2 to 73:
[image]

But when I use `idelta(order_created[1m])` to retrieve data, I can only see 3 new orders created:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `increase(order_created[1m])` instead of `idelta(order_created[1m])`, since `idelta()` returns the difference between two last samples before every point on the graph. It doesn't take into account other samples on the given lookbehind window in square brackets (1 minute in this case).
Unfortunately, the `increase(...)` function in Prometheus also may return unexpected results. For instance, it can return fractional number for integer counters or it can return too low number. [This article](https://medium.com/@romanhavronenko/victoriametrics-promql-compliance-d4318203f51e) explains the reasons behind this and provides the solution - to use [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html), which returns expected results from `increase(...)` over integer counter.